# php.ini doesn't load

Tags: php

I would like to ask for help, I just installed Apache and PHP on my PC. However my php.ini doesn't seem to load (php_ini_loaded_file(); returns false). When I check phpinfo(); there is "Configuration File (php.ini) Path "="C:\Windows" - which is directory where my php.ini file is. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for a file called `httpd.conf` this will be in your apache or apache2 folder

There should be some lines like:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/Windows"
</IfModule>
```

The path should point to the directory that your php.ini file is in, with no trailing slash. Once set remember to restart apache.

More info about configuration changes can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

I and allot of windows users use [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for development on windows, Its a breeze to setup out of box with everything required to get you started.